# Creating a multiline TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that should be 4 lines long .

```
First line text should be "YES"
Second Line ="No"
Third Line = "true"
Fourth line + "false"
```

How can this be done with a single `TextView`?

Comment: first post your code what have you tried

Comment: dude if my answer is helpful to u then u can vote up

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try following for **multiline** TextView.

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="4" 
    android:singleLine="false" 
    android:text="YES\nNo\ntrue\nfalse" />
```

You can try `\n` to set text in next line.

Comment: Can I make it multiple lines, but show 4 lines and if overflowed, show scroll or swipe up/down?

Comment: Yes you can assign as many lines as required and you have to set textview inside scrollview to make it moveable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="4"
    android:text="YES\nNo\ntrue\nfalse" />
```