# How textview support json code?

Tags: android

I use this json code in a url in web and I get it in a textview.

```
[

  {
    "des": "text\r\ntext2\r\ntest3"
  }
]
```

Show in text view

```
texttext2text3
```

In textview display my text in one line but i want displayed it in multiline.

```
text
text2
text3
```

can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a line break in an Android TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you !

> parse this json and get HTML as a string.

```
String htmlStringGot = parsedJSONStringValue;

txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(htmlStringGot).toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `TextView`

```
<TextView 
    android:maxLines="3"   
/>
```

> [Multi line textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815093/creating-a-multiline-textview)

Hope this helps u out.